# How to concat two pivot tables without losing column name

Tags: python, concatenation

I am trying to concat two pivot tables but after join the two tables, the columns lost.

Pivot1:

```
SATISFIED_CHECKOUT             1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
SEGMENT                                                    
BOTH_TX_SPEND_GROWN            0.01  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.80
BOTH_TX_SPEND_NO_GROWTH        0.01  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2018               NaN  0.03  0.04  0.15  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2019              0.01  0.02  0.05  0.13  0.78
ONLY_SPEND_GROWN               0.01  0.02  0.03  0.12  0.82
ONLY_TX_GROWN                  0.01  0.03  0.03  0.14  0.79
SHOPPED_NEITHER                 NaN  0.04  0.02  0.15  0.79
```

Pivot2:

```
SATISFIED_FOOD                 1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
SEGMENT                                                    
BOTH_TX_SPEND_GROWN            0.00  0.01  0.07  0.20  0.71
BOTH_TX_SPEND_NO_GROWTH        0.00  0.01  0.08  0.19  0.71
ONLY_SHOPPED_2018              0.01  0.01  0.07  0.19  0.71
ONLY_SHOPPED_2019              0.00  0.01  0.10  0.19  0.69
ONLY_SPEND_GROWN               0.00  0.01  0.08  0.18  0.72
ONLY_TX_GROWN                  0.00  0.02  0.07  0.19  0.72
SHOPPED_NEITHER                 NaN   NaN  0.10  0.20  0.70
```

The original df looks like below:

> ```
> SATISFIED_CHECKOUT         SATISFIED_FOOD           Persona
>         1                         1            BOTH_TX_SPEND_GROWN 
>         2                         3            BOTH_TX_SPEND_NO_GROWTH 
>         3                         2            ONLY_SHOPPED_2019 
>        ....                      ....             ............
>         5                         3            ONLY_SHOPPED_2019
> ```

I am using the code:

`a = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["SEGMENT"], columns=["SATISFIED_FOOD"], aggfunc='size').apply(lambda x: x / x.sum(), axis=1).round(2)`

`b = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["SEGMENT"], columns=["SATISFIED_CHECKOUT"], aggfunc='size').apply(lambda x: x / x.sum(), axis=1).round(2)`

`pd.concat([a, b],axis=1)`

The result like below:

```
                          1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0  ...   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
SEGMENT                                          ...                        
BOTH_TX_SPEND_GROWN      0.01  0.03  0.07  0.23  ...  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.80
BOTH_TX_SPEND_NO_GROWTH  0.01  0.03  0.06  0.22  ...  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2018        0.01  0.04  0.08  0.24  ...  0.03  0.04  0.15  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2019        0.01  0.03  0.08  0.25  ...  0.02  0.05  0.13  0.78
ONLY_SPEND_GROWN         0.00  0.03  0.07  0.22  ...  0.02  0.03  0.12  0.82
ONLY_TX_GROWN            0.01  0.02  0.05  0.22  ...  0.03  0.03  0.14  0.79
SHOPPED_NEITHER           NaN  0.01  0.07  0.28  ...  0.04  0.02  0.15  0.79
[7 rows x 15 columns]
```

But what I want to see this the result like below:

```
                        SATISFIED_CHECKOUT             SATISFIED_FOOD
                          1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0  ...   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
SEGMENT                                          ...                        
BOTH_TX_SPEND_GROWN      0.01  0.03  0.07  0.23  ...  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.80
BOTH_TX_SPEND_NO_GROWTH  0.01  0.03  0.06  0.22  ...  0.03  0.04  0.14  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2018        0.01  0.04  0.08  0.24  ...  0.03  0.04  0.15  0.78
ONLY_SHOPPED_2019        0.01  0.03  0.08  0.25  ...  0.02  0.05  0.13  0.78
ONLY_SPEND_GROWN         0.00  0.03  0.07  0.22  ...  0.02  0.03  0.12  0.82
ONLY_TX_GROWN            0.01  0.02  0.05  0.22  ...  0.03  0.03  0.14  0.79
SHOPPED_NEITHER           NaN  0.01  0.07  0.28  ...  0.04  0.02  0.15  0.79
[7 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: please format your data properly

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can work with. It is also part of the problem-solving process, and might help you along the way.

Comment: You should also add the starting dataframe `df` (or a subsample of it)